# php masking string with another string

Tags: php, url, masking

is there any way to masking string from an URL with another string from a variable?
I have these variables

```
$keyword = 'stackoverflow';
$foo = $keyword;
$bar = 'main-category';
```

what I want to show in the browser is: `http://example.com/main-category/page=2`
but this URL will make a request to: `http://example.com/$keyword/page=2`

Please don't tell me it can be achieved with htaccess because the keyword is changing dynamically, and also this on the client side, not all user able to modify htaccess / nginx.conf

edit : the URL above is just as an illustration, my point is 
how to call the $keyword variable with $bar variable

i have try with

```
$foo = $bar
echo $foo
```

this indeed echoing 'main-category' but it doesnt pass the real $foo variable

Thank you.

Comment: I'm confused, that will only make three variables, and I don't see how it's related to the url.  It could be but not in the code provided.  In any case if you wish to put the value in a string (variable interpolation) then use double quotes or concatenate it.  `"http://example.com/$keyword/page=2"`  although I prefer `"http://example.com/{$keyword}/page=2"` as it's a bit more readable.  OR  `'http://example.com/'.$keyword.'/page=2'`

Comment: I think he’s asking how to retrieve a dynamic variable from the url where “main-category” is the variable?

Comment: i've edit my question, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for you but the way based on htaccsess .

You will take the keyword on get parametrs .

Follow those steps :

1) Add this RewriteRule into .htaccsess file

RewriteRule test/(.*)/page=2?$ test2.php?keyword=$1 [L]

2) Create test2.php in your main folder (you feel free for naming the file,usually developers using index.php for handle all such requests)

And put those codes into the page

```
$keyword = htmlscpecialchars($_GET['keyword']);

echo "The keyword is "$keyword;
```

Thus you will get the keyword . Dont forget your url will be http://example.com/test/{keyword}/page=2 . You can change or remove "test" part kindly.

Best regards .

Answer (score 0):

It's still entirely unclear in what context you want to apply another variable. Or why.

Anyway, before anyone mentions varvars, what you probably need is a simple map:

```
$map = array(
     "main-category" => "stackoverflow",
     '$keyword' => "bazbazbaz",
);
$bar = "main-category";
$foo = $map[$bar];
```

Which allows "rewriting" keywords or variable-style placeholders within the application context.

Comment: If you meant something else, please do *not* leave a comment. Don't care.